# How to Display Text on PC Startup before Booting Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I am new to Ubuntu and I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
I want to know about the Boot file of Ubuntu.
Like in Windows we have a boot.ini file, there must be a similar file in Ubuntu which would boot it. I want to know which file is it and how to edit that file in such a way that when I power on my PC it would first display a text which I want to show and then boot Ubuntu.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The file is the /etc/default/**grub**

--1--

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/20348-ubuntu-login-to-text-mode-without-removing-gui

**Ubuntu. Login to text mode. It is not need to remove GUI from the system.**

You can leave it and just make your default boot as a text mode and if once you need a GUI you can restore it so easy.

open /etc/default/**grub** as and add text to the

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And in the file, change this line:

**`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`**

Then update your Grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Your system will then always boot to text mode.

If you once want to use GUI you can easly make light works

**`sudo service lightdm start`**

---2-----

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/19783-grub-customizer-301-released-and-ppa-installation-instructions-included

**Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the GRUB2/BURG settings and menuentries**

Features:
* move, remove or rename menuentries (they stey updatable by update-grub)
* edit the contents of menuentries or create new ones (internally it edits the 40_custom)
* support for GRUB2 and BURG
* reinstallation of the bootloader to MBR
* settings like default operating system, kernel params, background image and text colors etc.
* changing the installed operating system by running on a live cd

What is new in version 3.0.1

- entries can be moved free now
- integrated settings dialog
- new partition chooser
- context menu
- multi selection
- trash instead of checkboxes
- entry editor
- graphical error handlung
- reset functionality
- warning when trying to remove script- or system entries

**Install Grub Customizer 3.0.1 in ubuntu**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. That helped me a lot. I need an other little bit of help. I have installed g++ in my Ubuntu i want to make a c++ program which would open this file and when i do the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text" changes in the /etc/default/grub file the c++ program will do the rest of the work. Can this be done.??  @ptheo